# In `iex` shell, is it possible to call `*Test.exs` function directly?

Tags: elixir

In `import_test.exs` file, there is function as follows:

```
# @tag :external
test "extract_csv, header_only/1" do
  file = Path.join([:code.priv_dir(:mirror), "test", "head_only.csv"])
  batch = %Imports.Batch{internal_csv_path: file, importer_id: 1}
  Imports.extract_csv(batch)
  products = Imports.list_products()
  IO.inspect(products, label: "before")
  assert products == []
end
```

how to call it directly in shell? If running `mix test --only external`, the db update result won't be viewed because the `test` environment's automatically rollback operation after every unit test.

Now I copy the every  line of `test` into `iex` shell. Is it necessary?

when compile `imports_test.exs`, it gives the following message.

```
c("test/mirror/imports_test.exs") 
** (CompileError) test/mirror/imports_test.exs:2: module Mirror.DataCase is not loaded and could not be found
    (elixir 1.13.4) expanding macro: Kernel.use/1
    test/mirror/imports_test.exs:2: Mirror.ImportsTest (module)
```

test module header is as follows:

```
defmodule Mirror.ImportsTest do
  use Mirror.DataCase

  alias Mirror.Imports
```

Comment: Assuming you have a typical phoenix project structure, if don't set `MIX_ENV=test` before running iex, `elixirc_paths` in your `mix.exs` probably don't include `test/support` where your `DataCase` is defined.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this function is located in `test/my_test.ex` file, in the module named `MyTest`, you might do the following.

```elixir
iex||1 ▸ c "test/my_test.exs"
[SiblingsTest]
iex||2 ▸ MyTest.__info__(:functions)
[
  __ex_unit__: 0,
  __ex_unit__: 2,
  "test extract_csv, header_only/1": 1,
  ...
]
```

That means, you might apply it as

```elixir
apply(MyTest, :"test extract_csv, header_only/1", [%{}])
```

The last argument would be context. Please note, that neither `setup/1` nor any other callback would not have been called.

Comment: I have added `c` command result in the above post.

Comment: Compile everything needed then.